# Why gravitational wave stretches in one direction and at the same time it is squashed in another direction at right angle?

Tags: general-relativity, gravitational-waves

Does it means the amount of the stretching must be equal to the squashing due to some conservation laws or because the math in GR dictates? Ligo mirrors are obviously placed deliberately so as they are expecting this kind of stretching for gravitational wave since they are transverse wave?

Answer (score 1):

Gravitational waves (in vacuum) are solutions to the vacuum Einstein equations, which just say that the Ricci tensor vanishes. The Ricci tensor is related to changes in the volume of the space.